# Theoretical knowledge for a self taught web developer?

Tags: network-programming, theory

I am a University student in Mechanical engineering, but my true passion is computer programming. I am working on various projects,mainly web developing. Although I am doing fine and my level in coding really good according to code reviews I got from post-graduate students, I am an admirer of the theoretical knowledge and I believe getting more of it will make me better at what I am doing.

The thing is I don't know what classes I should take and what keywords I should google as the field of programming is too broad.

Are there any resources that could be of use to self-taught programmers relative to programming generally and web development too.

Comment: This will be closed in short order for being off-topic but as a starter, read about data structures and algorithms. Individual technologies are a lot easier once you understand the basics.

Comment: Why is this off topic ? Sorry for asking I am really new to this! I am not asking for tutorials, just for keywords to google.

Comment: I'd [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)